# Android sql update

Tags: android, sql-update

I am trying to update all rows in table and it's not working.

```
 String query="UPDATE "+TABLE_APPS+" SET "+KEY_APP_CHECK+" = '1'";
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        db.rawQuery(query, null);
        db.close(); // Closing database connection
```

It doesn't show any exception but data is not updated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use db.execSQL instead of db.rawQuery to compile and run your sql.

Answer (score 0):

Is the best option:

`ContentValues cvs = new ContentValues();
cvs.put(KEY_APP_CHECK, 1); 
db.update(TABLE_APPS, cvs, null, null);`

Comment: It's [Faster way -link](http://www.codeofaninja.com/2013/12/android-sqlite-transaction-tutorial.html) Most probably you won't see any difference.   But with ContentValues code looks more clean. If there will be more complex queries.